# Split Tunnelling for Websites that has different Servers

Tags: networking, vpn, tunnel, split-tunnel

Assume, In my router I have activated two packages. One gives me normal data and the other gives unlimited youtube access. If I use a VPN, it routes all traffics through it's server which will just finish using my regular data for youtube usage. When I was trying to find a solution for this, I came across an VPN feature, "Split Tunnelling" and I tried to use it. The problem I have in using this is. My VPN shows only two options exclude or include, apps or ip_address but not for a domain name. When I `ping youtube.com` without VPN and with VPN the IP Addresses are different. So, I am not sure how to set this up.

Is there any workaround to exclude domain youtube.com on proton vpn.

Comment: By 'normal data' do you mean it's a metered/limited connection? I can't see any other reason you wouldn't have 'unlimited youtube' on any internet connection.

Comment: To be more clear for example I have a data package that gives me 20GB for internet usage. And also I have another data package that gives unlimited access to YouTube only. If I connect through vpn isp will detect the usage is going not through youtube ip and it doesn't know I am using youtube. so instead of using the youtube unlimited package. It starts charging from that 20GB data. That is why I wan't to ignore only youtube.com from vpn usage.